# Is It Possible/Practical to Have the Shape and Amount of Convolution Kernels be Dynamic?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, convolution, conv-neural-network

I have a fairly basic understanding of CNN's. However, I saw this paper: http://www.cs.tau.ac.il/~wolf/papers/dynconv.pdf and I wondered if it would be possible to let the CNN decide what size and the amount of convolution kernels (probably not both of these things in the same CNN). Has a similar idea been done before (and what were the results)? Am I missing a piece of math about CNNs that makes it obvious that this would be not feasible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Optimization over discrete objects (integers) is usually **extremely hard**, it leads to combinatorial optimization, which is not a feasible approach to learning. This is why it is more typical to instead have **too many** parameters, neurons, layers or kernels - and simply add penalty for complexity so your model "prefers" to use as few as possible instead of trying to do "proper" optimization over structures. So yes, there is a very important, big mathematical problem here - you cannot differentiate with respect to the architectures, and differentiation is what drives nearly all modern ML techniques (in particular - CNNs).

That being said, there are still dozens, if not hundreads of papers which try to do that, by applying various metaoptimization methods on these variables (since, as said before - you cannot apply "good" optimization and you are pretty much left with heuristics). What are the results? Usually you get slight increase at the cost of huge computational cost (since you are usually training **a lot** of models instead of a single one). Consequently I never seen real "state of the art results" based on this methodology - usually well established architecture with additional penalties and variance reduction by creating an ensemble of models (like 10 neural nets) is way more powerful, especially given typical engineering/computational budget.